# "beef cacky" and "cheese cacky" as physical descriptions

Tags: expressions

Can "beef cacky" or "cheese cacky" be used to describe the physique of a person?
I don't know where does this come from, but I found a reference here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fH2Pg0W3lok&feature=player_detailpage#t=80s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you mean [beefcake](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/beefcake) or [cheesecake](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cheesecake). These mean pictures of attractive and scantily-dressed men and women respectively, or men and women who would be suited to appearing in such pictures. So, yes, it could be used to describe the physique of a person, suggesting that they were physically attractive specimens.